# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, grasshopper

I get the following error message with the code below. I am not sure if this has to do with the Grasshopper kernel or if I am not writing the `DataAccess.GetDataList()` method correctly. I hope you can help.

`The type arguments for method 'Grasshopper.Kernel.IGH_DataAccess.GetDataList<T>(int, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

code:

```
protected override void RegisterInputParams(GH_Component.GH_InputParamManager pManager)
{
pManager.AddTextParameter("SomeString", "SS", "Send Some String Somwhere", GH_ParamAccess.list); //0
}
protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{

string SomeString = default(string);
DA.GetDataList(0, ref SomeString);

if (!DA.GetDataList(0, ref SomeString)) return;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says the function requires an `int` and a `List<T>` but you're supplying an `int` and a `string`. You also don't need the `ref` modifier.

You need to do something like this:

```
List<string> someStrings = new List<string>();
if(! DA.GetDataList(0, someStrings)) return;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lee, it works, why is the ref modifier not needed there?

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani - The `ref` modifier is used to pass arguments by reference, and needs to be specified in the declaring method and at each call to the method. It is only required if the method needs to modify a variable passed to it as an argument.